# Что использовать для создания моделей сортировки товаров в магазине на Django?

Tags: python, django, django-model, интернет-магазин

Пытаюсь реализовать сортировку товаров подобную той, что на скриншоте:
[image: Скриншот сортировки]

Нашел несколько вариантов сделать это, много где советуют использовать EAV либо JSONField, и вот не знаю, какой вариант предпочтительнее, с одной стороны, чтобы реализовать это через json нужно просто добавить поле в модель подкатегории и товара, а потом просто выводить из подкатегории все поля для сортировки, а из товара выводить возможные варианты сортировки забирая значение по ключу, {поле сортировки: значение у товара}.
Либо же по каким то причинам нужно использовать именно EAV?